# How to Calculate DayOfWeek in Ms Excel

Tags: c#, excel

In MS Excel with US English culture, while checking the Day of the week for the Date "1/1/1900", it returns `SUNDAY`, whereas in [DayofWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8) property of `DateTime`, it returns `MONDAY`. Also, checked with the `Calender`, it shows `DayOFWeek` for the Date "1/1/1900" is Monday. Hence, can any one please explain the behavior of `DayOfWeek` in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

January 1, 1990 was a Monday ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1900#January_1,*1900*(Monday)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1900#January_1,_1900_(Monday)))

- The "WEEKDAY" Excel function returns a number from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday) representing the day of the week of a date.
- `System.DayOfWeek` is an enumeration going from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday)  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8)

You pointed out a well known problem. As explained here, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year

> "The WEEKDAY function returns incorrect values for dates before March 1, 1900. Because most users do not use dates before March 1, 1900, this problem is rare."

See also this answer: https://superuser.com/a/481499